# Using context in React while using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, spring, hibernate, react-hooks

Ok, I am pulling my hair out.

I am trying to utilize useEffect in my context to populate a list on screen.

```
  useEffect(() => {

    Axios.get("http://localhost:8080/getItems").then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      setItems(response.data);
    });
  }, [items]);
```

This allows me to populate the list each time I add an item to the database. However, it causes an endless loop in Spring.

Now, I can stop the endless loop by changing [items] to []. Yet, when I add to my database it no longer renders the change on the screen.

Does anyone know a workaround to the problem? To be exact, I still want to render an updates to the database without having an endless loop

Comment: *Yet, when I add to my database it no longer renders the change on the screen.* Start with that, and try debugging - are you sure `response.data` exists, and is of the expected type?

Comment: If you want to know that a data has been updated, you may need to use a subscription like socket.io or another thing. Something should be warn you when it's updated or you can trigger getItems after added your data from FE.

Comment: response.data exists, I can get it to update the new database item, but only by adding [items] as my second argument, which causes the endless loop

Comment: Are you adding things to the database from the same screen you are rendering the items?

Answer (score 0):

If you update your database you are not going to receive the changes in your frontend if you don't perform a request to get them.

There are a several mechanims to achieve that:

- Pull (every X period of time you perform a request asking for changes)
- Push your backend notifies frontend when a new change is performed.

Pull mechanisn is the one you called endless loop.

Push mechanins you need to use websockets for example or a library like socket.io to perform it.

Answer (score 0):

First you change items array which fires useEffect, after when items are fetched you change it again and useEffect fires again. Thats why you get endless loop.

You can try to do something like this:

```
const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

const pushItem = (item) => { // Place where you add new item.
    setItems([...items, item]);
    setIsLoaded(false);
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoaded) {
        return;
    }
    Axios.get("http://localhost:8080/getItems").then((response) => {
        setItems(response.data);
        setIsLoaded(true);
    });
}, [items, isLoaded]);
```

Comment: Did you mean to say ```const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
```

Comment: yeah, my bad. useEffect => useState